# Could we maintain Application insights in azure based on Client?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have one function app like **Y**.
And the clients are like **X1** and **X2**
When we are hitting the function app **Y** through **X1** and **X2**

Can we maintain logs in Application insights seperately means seperate for **X1** and **X2**?

Means functionAPP is one and clients are seperate

Comment: Can you please provide more details? function app means azure function? and how do you introduce the application insights to your project? and how do you hit the function through client x1 and x2?

Comment: function app means azure functions only 
when we are creating a function app in azure they have given option called enable the application insights  if we enable it then the application insights is enabled 
after we maintain the instrumentation key in localsettings.json
we wrote some code in to azure function app to log errors

assume X1 and X2 are like angulare jS applications y is function app (azure functions) So Like webapi x1 and x2  hit this function app through Angular js and get response.

Did u understand?